# HTML5 FileReader equivalent for nodejs 'fs'

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, html5-filesystem

I was trying to read and write a file in javascript. Nodejs 'fs'is not working. I came to know that there is an equivalent HTML5 API's.

What is the equivalent for

```
fs.writeFile('my.file', filedata)
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/dir/leaves.file')
```

in HTML5 filereader api

Comment: You are looking for the FileReader: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: can you tell me an exact equivalent? I am little confused @GetOffMyLawn

Comment: There is no* `fs` equivalent in web APIs, for obvious security reasons. `fs`-> *`f`ile`s`ystem*, and browsers won't give access to the user's filesystem to any random script on the web. You can read files with a FileReader, you can load files from a server with XHR, or you can ask your user to give you files from their f-s, and you can prompt your user to save files. But none of these operations will be done directly from the user's file-system, without his action. (*well actually we could consider IndexedDB and alike as filesystems...)

Comment: @Kaiido . Can you post that as an answer? I will close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no* `fs` equivalent in web APIs, for obvious security reasons.

`fs` -> `f`ile`s`ystem, and browsers won't give access to the user's filesystem to any random script on the web.

- You can read files with a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/),
- you can load files from a server with [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or you can ask your user to [give you files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) from their filesystem,
- and you can [prompt your user to save files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download).

But none of these operations will be done directly from the user's file-system, without his own action.

(*Actually we could consider IndexedDB and alike as filesystems, but they can't be compared to `fs` either...)

Answer (score -2):

You can load files using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) like so:

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<img id='output'>
```